# Find date in string

Tags: java

I am using some code I found to find dates in a string with a slight modification to handle both two and four year dates.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](2[0][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9])").matcher(msgBody.substring(iStart));
while (m.find()) {
        allMatches[count] = m.group();
        count++;
}
```

It returns most of the two and four digit year dates in the strings I am searching but does not return a result when the string contains "*Valid 11/3/14-11/9/14 ".

I am looking to return "11/3/14" for the first find and "11/9/14" for the second find.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample input contains single digit days of the month, which are not allowed by your regexp; it'll match "11/03/14" but not "11/3/14".

I think your `0[1-9]` should be `0?[1-9]` if you want to match single digit numbers.

```
Pattern.compile(
    "(0?[1-9]|1[012])"
    + "[- /.]"
    + "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"
    + "[- /.]"
    + "(2[0][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9])"
)
```

or you could add a negative lookbehind to make sure you don't match a month in the middle of a larger number and simplify this to

```
Pattern.compile(
    "(?<![0-9])"  // Don't start match in middle of a number.
    + "(0?[1-9]|1[012])"  // Month of year
    + "[- /.]"  // Separator
    + "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"  // Day of month
    + "[- /.]"  // Separator
    + "(20[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9])"  // 2 or 4 digit year
    + "(?![0-9])"  // Don't match if year continues.
)
```

Of course, assuming MONTH/DAY/YEAR ordering is problematic if you're serving non-American users.

If you haven't already, see ["Falsehoods programmers believe about time"](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time).

Also, your code will parse the birthday of anyone who is 15 or older as having been born in 1920.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I missed the one digit month issue.  Thankfully, the incoming strings are all from the U.S. so date formatting is pretty straight forward.